# Facebook query doesn't return expected hometown name parameter

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve the user hometown through the [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API), but the problem is my request only returns me the id and not the name of the hometown. It's the same when I try to enter information straight as a [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) in the browser. Here is my code

```
//Retrieve hometown
$objet = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$user['id'].'?fields=hometown&'.$app_access_token);
if (json_decode($objet,true) != NULL) {
    $user_infos = json_decode($objet,true);
    $user['hometown'] = $user_infos['hometown']['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

User should be connected with you app and grant `user_hometown` permission before you able to access that field, you also need to use user's `access_token` instead of application `access_token`.

Beware that many users doesn't fill that field on Facebook, in that case you will get empty results even for users who granted required permissions.

BTW, there is also `user_location` permission which allow you to query `location` field of `user` which is different than `hometown`...

Comment: Very usefull. The only thing i am missing is the user's access token. How can i get it?

Comment: There is couple of ways depending on SDK you use. But generally you get one by [authenticating the user](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).